# In Marionette JS, how can I add a field from another model to a td in a table row?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I created a table from a composite view, with a model item template:

```
<script id="vehicle-table-row" type="text/template">
 <td><a href="/vehicles/<%- id %>"><%- id %></a></td>
 <td><%- make %></td>
 <td><%- model %></td>
 <td></td>
</script>
```

I need to add a value of a field from a different model into the last cell in my row.  I haven't found any docs that shows how to do this.

How can I "combine" two models into one template?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ItemView you can use [serializeData](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-serializedata) for custom serialization.
For instance:

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.otherModel = options.otherModel;
  },

  serializeData: function(){
    return _.extend({}, this.model.toJSON(), this.otherModel.toJSON());
  }
});
```

This will make both your main ItemView model (`this.model`) and your secondary model (`this.otherModel`) attributes available in the template. Be careful if the models have attribute names which are the same.